# XAML icons in menu items look shifted

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to use [Visual Studio 2022 Image Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) in my project. The one that the VS2022 IDE uses (surprise!). But when I add an icon to a menu item, it doesn't look as pretty as it does in a VS menu:

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
  <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource canvas}" Geometry="F1M16,16H0V0H16Z" />
            <DrawingGroup Opacity="{DynamicResource cls-1}">
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey-10}" Geometry="F1M14.5,4.5v10H3.5V7.95A4.984,4.984,0,0,0,8,3a4.966,4.966,0,0,0-.254-1.5H11.5Z" />
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-defaultgrey}" Geometry="F1M15,4.5v10l-.5.5H3.5L3,14.5V8a4.988,4.988,0,0,0,1-.1V14H14V5H11V2H7.9a4.968,4.968,0,0,0-.321-1H11.5l.354.146,3,3Z" />
            </DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource light-yellow}" Geometry="F1M3,2,3,0H4L4,2l-.5.5Zm.5,2.5L3,5V7H4V5Zm1-1L5,4,7,4V3L5,3Zm-2,0L2,3,0,3V4L2,4Zm1.708-.7h.708L6.328,1.378,5.62.671,4.208,2.088ZM2.792,4.206H2.085L.673,5.623l.707.706L2.793,4.913Zm1.414,0v.708L5.623,6.328l.706-.708L4.913,4.208ZM2.794,2.792V2.085L1.378.673.671,1.38,2.088,2.793Z" />
          </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
      </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

Compare the IDE's and my renders (scaled):

[image]

As you can see, my icons seem to be shifted horizontally by a fraction of a pixel. Perhaps it's just because Microsoft guys used PNG instead of XAML.

I've tried adding `SnapsToDevicePixels` wherever possible, but it doesn't change anything. Obviously, specifying a correct offset will be enough for the solution, but I don't know that offset. And I don't want to look through the Magnifier every time I add a new icon to make sure I need to subtract a hundredth of a pixel from the offset I guessed.

Could you suggest an elegant solution to removing the subpixel effect when rendering these XAML icons?

Comment: Not sure it works but have you tried `UseLayoutRounding`?

Comment: @emoacht Thank you! I completely forgot about `UseLayoutRounding`. This your assumption is definitely the correct solution. I want to mark your comment as the answer.